# android: R file automatically generates an error

Tags: android, r.java-file

In my android project my R file automatically generates an error at the following line:

```
 public static final int searchOptions]=0x7f080002;
```

here searchOptions is a radioGroup. If I edit this file it reverts back to this line again.
Cleaning the project doesn't work nor does deleting the file or deleting the gen folder.

Any clues what might cause this and how to fix it?

Cheers!

Comment: show your layout file. Also check you use most recent version of ADT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the android:id attribute had this id.
While the xml parser had no problem with the id, the R file did, resulting in an error.
Removing the bracket in the id attribute fixed it.